# Округлить целое число в большую сторону

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть число, например **66241** . 
Каким образом получить "круглое" число - `66300` ?

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$number = 66241;
$result = (ceil($number/100))*100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот функция которая округляет, но из 66241 она не выдаст 66300, так как 41 ближе к низу а вот 66251 будет 66300

```
 echo round(66251 , -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для округления до десятков - можно поделить число на 10, использовать функцию округления и умножить результат на 10. (56 / 10 = 5,6 -> 6 -> 6 * 10 = 60)
Для округления до сотен - можно поделить число на 100, использовать функцию округления и умножить результат на 100. (561 / 101 = 5,61 -> 6 -> 6 * 100 = 600)
Для тысяч, десятков тысяч и т.д. аналогично.
Извините, если не правильно понял ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = [66241, 15790, 25000];

function round_up($num, $precision) {
    $num = $num / pow(10, $precision);
    $num = ceil($num);
    return $num * pow(10, $precision);
}

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo round_up($number, 2) . "\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
66300
15800
25000
```